# Query to get part of string with partial matching of 2 strings

Tags: t-sql

I have a requirement where I need to match payee last name with register name and return pay name ,

we some time gets payee name with additional characters...
For example Pay name  is 'JOHNC'
and register name is 'MART JOHN KENNEDY' and return output JOHN as its partially matches.

Used below login in sql, but no luck, Please suggest what might be to improve myquery?

```sql
DECLARE @string1 VARCHAR(100) = 'JOHNC';
DECLARE @string2 VARCHAR(100) = 'MART JOHN KENNEDY';

DECLARE @startIndex INT = CHARINDEX(@string1, @string2);

IF @startIndex > 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result VARCHAR(100) = SUBSTRING(@string2, @startIndex, LEN(@string1));
    PRINT @result;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'No common substring found.';
END
```

Comment: Please tag the (R)DBMS you are using. T-SQL is used by several products.

Comment: How do *you*, and more importantly the data engine, know what those additional characters are?

Comment: What you ask for is fuzzy matching, not partial matching. `JOHNC` isn't even part of the name, and there may be millions people with that name. SQL, the language, doesn't have fuzzy matching

Comment: There are *text processing* algorithms that can be used for this, not SQL. Typically, this is the job of Full Text Search indexes (wouldn't work with partial words like this) , services like Elastic or libraries like FuzzyWuzzy in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Fuzzy matching is not going to perform well, and is generally a bad idea.

If you want to give it a go anyway, you could do something like this:

```
DECLARE @Payees TABLE (PayeeName NVARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @Payees (PayeeName) VALUES
('MART JOHN KENNEDY'), ('OHNCs fish and bait'), ('barts tavern');

DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(50) = 'JOHNC'

;WITH FourChars AS (
SELECT @Name AS FullString, '%'+SUBSTRING(@Name,1,4)+'%' AS ThisString, 1 AS StartPos, LEN(@Name) AS TotalLen
UNION ALL
SELECT FullString, '%'+SUBSTRING(FullString,StartPos+1,4)+'%', StartPos+1, TotalLen
  FROM FourChars
 WHERE StartPos + 4 <= TotalLen
)

SELECT p.PayeeName, fc.ThisString AS MatchedBy
  FROM @Payees p
    CROSS APPLY FourChars fc
 WHERE PayeeName LIKE ThisString;
```

| PayeeName | MatchedBy |
| --- | --- |
| MART JOHN KENNEDY | %JOHN% |
| OHNCs fish and bait | %OHNC% |

Here we're taking four character chunks of the `@Name` and using them to compare to the PayeeNames. If we find a match, then we return the row.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to [`string_split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) the *register name* on spaces and then try to find a *starting with* match (`PayeeName like RegisterNameSegment + '%'`) against the *payee name* and hope for the best.

```
declare @PayeeName as VarChar(64) = 'JOHNC';
declare @RegisterName as VarChar(64) = 'Mart John Kennedy';

select @PayeeName as PayeeName, value as RegisterNameSegment,
  case when @PayeeName like value + '%' then 'close enough' else 'nope' end as Match
  from String_Split( @RegisterName, ' ' );
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XPb7J6P-).